# Want to Create Chrome Extension like Tool Tip

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am new to google Chrome Extension i have create Google Chrome Extension like as :

[image]

Using this code :

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Hello World!",
  "description": "My first Chrome App.",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": { "16": "calculator-16.png", "128": "calculator-128.png" }
}
```

and background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
    'bounds': {
      'width': 400,
      'height': 500
    }
  });
});
```

my google Chrome Extension will be open like popup but want to open my app like tooltip like this

[image]

So Please help me how to open app like this..

Thanks

Comment: As belykh correctly said, what you made is not an **extension** but an **app**.

Answer (score 3):

You should create an extension instead of an application, and add `popup` in the manifest.
Look at this:

```
{
    "name": "Hello World!",
    "description": "My first Chrome App.",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "images/icon19.png",
            "38": "images/icon38.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Calculator",
        "default_popup": "window.html"
    },
    "icons": { "16": "calculator-16.png", "128": "calculator-128.png" }
}
```

You can read docs https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction